# vue looping an object to render multiple versions of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

I am wanting to put multiple components in a wrapper, so it would look like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <component />
    <component />
    <component />
</div>
```

I am trying the following,

```
<component
     v-for="person in persons"
     :key="person.key"
     :is="chooseType(person)"
     :person="person"
     :feed="person.self ? handle : aFunction(person)"
     :publisher="getPublisher(person)"
/>
```

My problem is that person is returning as undefined when it runs the `chooseType` component, why would this be, the persons object is not null, so does have children. How can I loop a dynamic component, as I assume I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Show us the code for the `chooseType()` method which returns the component name.

Comment: Perhaps you have NULL items in the array ?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the `chooseType()` method. What does it look like?

Comment: @Terry @Ninowis There is nothing wrong with the `ChooseType()` method it takes an argument `person` but when I break with `ChooseType`, `person` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`v-for` is used along with `:is` in dynamic component. Please find below

```js
Vue.component('dynamic1', {
  template: '<div>Dynamic 1</div>'
})

Vue.component('dynamic2', {
  template: '<div>Dynamic 2</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      persons: [{
        name: 'dynamic1'
      }, {
        name: 'dynamic2'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getComponent(comp) {
      return comp
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component v-for="person in persons" :is="getComponent(person.name)"></component>
</div>
```